# How can I use functionality of Primary Key and Foreign Key in Clickhouse?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I recently created a relational database model and it has a lot of primary key and foreign key relations. I want to use clickhouse for my database but it turns out that clickhouse does not support foreign key and unique primary keys. Can someone tell me if I am missing anything here.

Answer (score 6):

You are right. CH does not have unique & foreign constraints.
Moreover JOINs are not the best part of ClickHouse.

ClickHouse suggests to create single wide denormalized table and avoid joins as possible.

Comment: I'm considering creating a driver that can extend the primaryKey and foreignKey but will want to confirm no such exist already.

Comment: There is no  primaryKey(uniqConstraint) and foreignKey in Clickhouse